# What is wrong with this code to print a pattern of spaces and asterisks?

Tags: python

I want to print the below pattern

```
        * 
      * *
    * * *
  * * * *
* * * * *
```

**My code :**

```
for row in range(1,6):
      print(' ' * (5-row) + row * '*')
```

The above code gives me expected output but does not add spaces after each `*`

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

when i am trying to add spaces it is printing as pyramid which is not expected output
any suggestions

```
print(' ' * (5-row) + row * '* ')  -> space added after `'*  '` 

    * 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

Comment: "when i am trying to add spaces it is printing as pyramid which is not expected output any suggestions" Well, in your own words, what actually is wrong with that result? Like, in terms of the number of spaces and asterisks? How many spaces should appear before the star on the first line? How many do appear?

Comment: Please note that the [design-patterns] tag, and the idea of "design patterns" generally, has **nothing to do with** using text to draw patterns at the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to increase the size of the padding; try the following:

```py
for row in range(1, 6):
    print(' ' * (5 - row) * 2 + row * '* ')
#         *
#       * *
#     * * *
#   * * * *
# * * * * *
```

Or, you can use f-string with `join`:

```py
for i in range(1, 6):
    print(f"{' '.join('*' * i):>9}")
#         *
#       * *
#     * * *
#   * * * *
# * * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

Print white-spaces for `n-i` first then print the required character(s) for `i` number of times, where `i` is the individual number from `1` to `n`. You can implement the code in a function, so that it works for any value of `n`:

```py
def printPattern(n=5):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print('  ' * (n - i) + '* ' * i)
```

**OUTPUT:** For different values of `n`:

```py
>>> printPattern(2)
  * 
* *  
>>> printPattern() # default n is 5
        * 
      * * 
    * * * 
  * * * * 
* * * * * 
>>> printPattern(10)
                  * 
                * * 
              * * * 
            * * * * 
          * * * * * 
        * * * * * * 
      * * * * * * * 
    * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * *
```